# Setting alarms daily android

Tags: android, android-activity, alarmmanager, android-alarms, alarms

I want to make my application set alarms every day at lets say 7 am a list of pills for the user. So far I have been doing it when a user adds a new pill, I will set the alarm directly, but I want to make it set alarms for today only. I am able to get a list of pills for some day using xpath, and getting the pills in a list. Now I was thinking if this is feasible to have some kind of hidden activity that keeps running or something that will set the daily pills. If someone could give me directions as to what I should be looking for to solve this problem, any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use: [Alarm Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). And place it in [Service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html). Read also about [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html)

Answer (score 0):

I will give an idea for this.

1. Schedule the first `Alarm` at **7 am** using the set method of `AlarmManager` and register a `BroadcastReceiver` to be executed at 7 am using the same `AlarmManager`.
2. At **7 am** your `Alarm` and `BroadcastReceiver`  will execute. In the `onReceive` method of your `BroadcastReceiver` again set the `Alarm` and `BroadcastReceiver` so that it becomes a self loop.

pseudo code to set broadcastReceiver class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, broadcastReceiver.class);
                intent.putExtra("subject", subject);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                        0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
AlarmManager am= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, "Your specific time", pendingIntent);
```

broadcastReceiver.class:

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
//set the alarm and broadcast receiver again
}
```